# getting error: Background.png is not a valid PNG file with required size

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, testing, marketplace

I’m in the process of testing a Windows Phone 7 app using the test kit but receive an error relating to the background.png dimensions

When running the test kit it says:

```
Result            Test Name                          Test Description     
Failed       XAP Package Requirement        Validation of XAP file size and content files

                                Result Details
[ERROR] : Background.png is not a valid PNG file with the required size: 62 x 62
```

However when I change the dimensions to 62x62 it says the same, but saying the dimensions should be 173x173. I therefore wondered how to resolve this issue as I don’t recall changing any code relating to the background.png file..

Thanks

@Gambit Thanks both Icon and background where set to the background file.

Comment: This might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184844%28v=vs.92%29.aspx

Comment: Quick guess: you're supposed to have both (one of each size).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your WMAppManifest.xml, there is an entry called `<IconPath>`.  This should be set to the .png that is 62 x 62 (the small tile).

There is also an entry called `<PrimaryToken>` which should contain a .  This should be set to the .png that is 173 x 173 (the pinned tile).

Make sure both of these .pngs exist in your project and they are referenced correctly.